# React Native (iOS) app loads nicely on wifi; crashes on LTE/cell

Tags: ios, react-native

I've written a simple app for my iPhone that calls an API a dozen times (I'm using async/await for each) for public transportation stop predictions, and then assembles it into a page.

The app loads and displays without quickly on Wifi. However, on a robust LTE connection, it displays strange behavior:

- It gets stuck on the default "App name - Powered by React Native" splash screen
- You can see the rendered view only if you double-tap on the home button and view the app in the app chooser
- If you then choose the app, the properly rendered view shows but the app freezes (the home button is unresponsive to clicks) and then after 5 secs or so the app crashes

It does not appear to be related to the fact that LTE is a bit slower than my Wifi. The API payloads are small, and the LTE is pretty robust (tried in a few different locations; it was fast).

The entire `index.ios.js` is available here:
https://github.com/jasonmenayan/Muni/blob/master/index.ios.js

Comment: I'm experiencing the same symptoms with RN 0.33.0. I've uploaded [my package.json file here](https://gist.github.com/nitindhar7/4600127cfd951cdc46eddc4b86a54a91). I'm using fastlane to deploy to TestFlight using a `Release` scheme. According to [RN docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html) a release scheme _"will also load the JavaScript locally, so you can put the app on a device and test whilst not connected to the computer"_. I see a little bar at the top during the LaunchScreen saying "Loading from 192.168.." (a local IP address). Ugh. No luck so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is caused by build the app in Debug phase. The only thing you need to do, is going to xCode Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme, and change the Build Configuration in Run tab from "Debug" to "Release".

Please check the official doc and the issue here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12022